# Reading Multiple Xml in Vb Net?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have a problem reading my XML. My program does it well, at the beginning and then it fails. I have to read all the xml in a folder and show it on a excel sheet but my program reads all the files but just writes the last one on the folder. I think its a problem on the `For each` but I'm lost.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Version_xml As String
    Dim implocaltraladados As Decimal
    Dim implocalretenidos As Decimal
    Dim retenidos As Decimal
    Dim trasladados As Decimal
    Dim Subtotal As Decimal
    Dim valor_noIdentificacion As String
    Dim preciounitarioxml As Decimal
    Dim importeconcepto As Decimal
    Dim cantidadvendida As Decimal
    Dim subtotalclave As Decimal = 0
    Dim descripcionxml As String
    Dim Emisor_Nombre As String
    Dim total As Decimal
    Dim UUID As String
    Dim VarConceptos As XmlNodeList
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim VarDocumentoXML As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    Dim VarManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(VarDocumentoXML.NameTable)

    Dim folderPath = "C:\Users\C-Juarezl\Desktop\Xml\"


    For Each filePath In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        VarDocumentoXML.Load(filePath)  'Aqui puedes definir la ruta del archivo mediante un OpenFileDialog o  algun otro metodo para especificar
    Next
    VarManager.AddNamespace("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3")
    VarManager.AddNamespace("tfd", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital")
    VarManager.AddNamespace("implocal", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal")
    Version_xml = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/@Version", VarManager).InnerText
    total = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/@Total", VarManager).InnerText
    Emisor_Nombre = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor/@Nombre", VarManager).InnerText
    UUID = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital/@UUID", VarManager).InnerText
    Label2.Text = Emisor_Nombre
    Label4.Text = UUID
    Label5.Text = total.ToString("c")
    implocalretenidos = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/implocal:ImpuestosLocales/@TotaldeRetenciones", VarManager).InnerText
    implocaltraladados = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/implocal:ImpuestosLocales/@TotaldeTraslados", VarManager).InnerText
    retenidos = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/@TotalImpuestosRetenidos", VarManager).InnerText
    trasladados = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/@TotalImpuestosTrasladados", VarManager).InnerText
    Subtotal = VarDocumentoXML.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/@SubTotal", VarManager).InnerText
    VarConceptos = VarDocumentoXML.SelectNodes("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto", VarManager)

    For Each node In VarConceptos
        valor_noIdentificacion = node.attributes("NoIdentificacion").value
        preciounitarioxml = node.attributes("ValorUnitario").value
        importeconcepto = node.attributes("Importe").value
        cantidadvendida = node.attributes("Cantidad").value
        subtotalclave = node.attributes("Importe").value
        descripcionxml = node.attributes("Descripcion").value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Each time you do `VarDocumentoXML.Load(filePath)` you wipe out the contents that were previously there.  So you need to move your entire logic into the `For Each` loop.  However, it's not really clear what you are doing with the XML documents.  Do you need to merge them somehow?  Can you reduce your question to a [mcve]?

Comment: For an example of what I mean by moving everything inside the `For Each` loop see https://dotnetfiddle.net/VxcQGn